# META-INF javascript reload AMP file

Tags: maven, jar, war, alfresco, meta-inf

I'm making an extension to alfresco and I created a surf page, with the files described in this tutorial: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-page.html

In this tutorial said too, that if I want a javascript/css file, I have to pus in the folder `/res/META-INF/tutorials/example.js`. When I run the project I generate a amp file with maven that I install on Alfresco in share.war file with MMT module -> `java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install <AMPFileLocation> <WARFileLocation>`. When I search the javascript file on Alfresco installation for example, the file is inside the jar `/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/lib/sign.jar`. When I open this jar, the javascript is updated when I install the new version. But when I run Alfresco, he runs older versions of this file. Any solution ? :( And sometimes other files not updated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that! If we want to reload ALL and we have old files, you can delete share folder inside `tomcat/webapps/` before make java to install on `share.war`. We can too delete `java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar uninstall <AMPFile> <WARFileLocation>` all the installation of the amp on the war file.